# Java String , trick in split

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I have a string with **`,`** separated I want to read till 4th index then remaining string I want to consider as one string.

**Like in below**

```
String str = "abc,xyz,123,789,ijk,1232,123,123,STU,PQR,111";
```

I want to split and take string after *ijk* in one string and from *abc* to *789* each part in different string.

Comment: You've described what you want. Maybe it's a good idea to start coding now? Come back here if you have an actual question.

Comment: maybe try it with an regex

Answer (score 0):

[`String::split` can take a second parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) indicating how many groups to form, which in your case is 5:

```
String[] result = str.split(",", 5);
```